# ffmpeg use on iOS

Tags: iphone, c++, c, ios, ffmpeg

I understand that to use FFmpeg in an iOS app, you use the ./configure and make to generate the .a files, that you will add to the project.

My question is, once the .a files show up in the project navigator and in the Link Binary With Libraries section, how do you actually use them in your classes?, I see there is no "framework" to use in an #import statement, so I don't know how to access the classes methods and properties.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to import header files (.h) in to your implementation (.m) files and continue. As an example ;

```
#import "avformat.h"

// Some code goes here

    /*
     *   avformat_open_input(AVFormatContext **ps, const char *filename, AVInputFormat *fmt, AVDictionary **options)
     */
    int openInputValue = avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, utf8FilePath, inputFormat, nil);
    NSLog(@"%s - %d # openInputValue = %d", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, openInputValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

every .a file have some implementation file, every implementation file have a interface file, objc-c the implementation file is .m/.mm, the interface file is .h like C/C++, so if you want use the library, you need import the header file(.h). the header file can tell you classes methods and properties